# Error API body type after build with node adapter

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

My app on SvelteKit + ts. I build `npm run build` (node adapter), with `npm run preview` (and with `npm run dev`) everything works. With node build

```
export async function post ({body}) {
   try {
     const login = body.get ('login');
```

```
error TypeError: body.get is not a function.
Content-Type request: application / x-www-form-urlencoded. Body is Uint8Array(34) in building app.
```

As I understand it, you need to screw the bode-parser somewhere. Or how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update @sveltejs/kit to 1.0.0-next.165 fix it =)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.